# Есть ли три элемента в массиве, сумма которых равна заданному числу

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, числа

Пусть дан массив и некое число x. Надо определить, существуют ли в нем три числа, сумма которых равна х.
Если было бы два числа - можно было бы отсортировать и бинпоиском для каждого числа a проверять наличие x - a. А тут как?

Comment: Элементы положительные? 4 прогона по циклу думаю достаточно

Comment: А точно так же... отсортировать - и понеслася. Цикл в цикле, а внутри твой бин-поиск.

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Finding three elements in an array whose sum is closest to a given number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2070359)

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** реализация алгоритма, представленного ниже, не работает. К примеру: `find_triplet_sum([0, 1, 2, 4, 5], 8)` не находит тройку индексов: 1, 2, 4.

---

Чтобы найти индексы `i,j,k` в массиве `a`, такие что `a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == x`, существует `O(n * log n)` алгоритм (из [ответа @olykos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34382390/4279)):

1. Отсортировать массив
2. Выбрать индексы `lo`, `hi`, соответствующие наибольшим и наименьшим значениям в массиве (первый и последний элементы в отсортированном массиве)
3. Затем, до тех пор пока можно выбрать третий элемент между lo, hi индексами:

   - с помощью двоичного поиска пытаемся найти `i` индекс, такой что:

     ```
     a[lo] + a[i] + a[hi] == x
     ```
   - если нашли, то алгоритм завершён
   - если сумма меньше, то увеличиваем `lo` (увеличиваем наименьший доступный элемент)
   - если сумма больше, то уменьшаем `hi` (уменьшаем наибольший доступный элемент)
4. Если не нашли, то алгоритм завершился неуспешно.

Реализация на Питоне:

```py
from bisect import bisect_left


def find_triplet_sum(a, x):
    a.sort()
    lo, hi = 0, len(a) - 1
    while lo + 1 < hi:
        i = bisect_left(a, x - a[lo] - a[hi], lo + 1, hi)  # binary search
        assert lo < i
        triplet_sum = a[lo] + a[i] + a[hi]
        if i == hi or triplet_sum < x:  # sum is too small
            lo += 1
        elif triplet_sum > x:  # sum is too big
            hi -= 1
        else:  # found
            assert lo < i < hi and triplet_sum == x
            return lo, i, hi
    raise ValueError("Can't find i,j,k such that: a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == x.")
```

где [`bisect_left()` реализует двоичный поиск](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left). Пример:

```py
>>> find_triplet_sum([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 3)
(0, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно: _если сумма меньше_. Если двоичный поиск завершился безрезультатно, то некоторые суммы могут быть меньше, а некоторые больше.

Comment: @VladD: на следующей строчке в ответе: *если сумма больше* (больше, меньше, равно -- других вариантов нет)

Comment: Всё равно непонятно. Двоичный поиск ничего не нашёл — о какой сумме идёт речь?

Comment: Пример. Целевая сумма 15, массив [0,1,9,10]. 0 + 1 + 10 слишком мало, 0 + 9 + 10 слишком много. О какой из этих двух сумм идёт речь?

Comment: (Вероятно, опечатка: «пытаемся найти `i` индекс» → «пытаемся найти индекс `j`»?)

Comment: @VladD двоичный поиск внутри bisect, а снаружи цикл линейный (на единицу граница слева или справа двигается). bisect не случайный индекс возвращает: все элементы в a[lo+1:i] меньше `(x - a[lo] - a[hi])`, а в a[i:hi] больше или равно. Это тонкий момент. Тестирование перебором показало, что функция может не найти подходящую тройку, даже если она есть: `find_triplet_sum([0, 1, 2, 4, 5], 8)` (тройка индексов: 1,2,4).

Comment: Ох. То есть тогда этот контрпример стоит запостить в оригинальный ответ?

Comment: @VladD оригинальный ответ использует слова "левая и правая половины". Сравнение с суммой должно было это намерение отразить. Но я уже не уверен. Я оставлю ответ, чтобы люди на те же грабли не нарывались.